# Mongoose $pull is not removing object from an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Book Model

```
const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    isbn: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Book", BookSchema );
```

Library Model

```
const LibrarySchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    booksList: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Book",
        },
    ],
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Library", LibrarySchema);
```

deleteBook

```
router.delete("/:libraryID/book/:isbn", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const book = await Book.findOne({
            isbn: req.params.isbn,
        });

        await Library.findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id: req.params.libraryID},
            {$pull: {booksList: {_id: book._id}}},
            {new: true},
            function (error, data) {
                console.log("Error: " + error);
                if(!error) {
                    res.status(200).send({
                        success: true,
                        message: "Book removed successfully",
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        res.send({success: false, error: err.message});
    }
});
```

I trying to pull a book with the object id from booksList array but nothing is working. I have tried almost every solution available on internet for this but nothing is working.

I always get this response but the book remains in the booksList array always.

```
{
  success: true,
  message: "Book removed successfully",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save a `reference` to another collection you are storing directly the `_id`. So your model has this example data:

```
[
  {
    "_id":1,
    "booksList":[1,2,3,4],
    "name":"name1"
  }
]
```

Note how `booksList` is an array of numbers, not an array of objects `{id: 1}`.

So your query has to be without `_id` in the object `_id: book._id`. Something like this:

```
{$pull: {booksList: book._id}},
```

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rFQyAMCnOz7) example.